# Design Patterns Question: Different types of filters for "Image Processor"

Tags: design-patterns

This is a strictly theoretical, architectural design patterns question:

Say we want to design a system that allows for different kinds of **filters** to be applied to images. In other words, an **image processor**.

What kind of design would you use?

I was thinking of the following: some kind of Factory for creating the concrete classes that extend/implement an abstract Filter object.

I'd appreciate any ideas about this job interview question.

(Another idea: template method for the filtering).

Comment: Hmm, just to clarify some stuff: the filters would be like a Set of Filters applied to an Image?

Comment: It would be better with some code.

Comment: @Guilherme Yes, some kind of vector containing all the filter types the client wants to apply to the image.

Comment: `Decorator Pattern` is always interesting where you are progressively processing something like a combination of filters.

Comment: @bcperth Thanks, I'll definitely look up Decorator Pattern and see how it applies to this design problem.

Comment: @Kata Good idea, though I think it's better to first draw some kind of UML diagram describing the different classes and their interactions.